# SQL missing dates null value how to fill

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi how do i fill up the null value with e.g **id**, **name**
from the left join table

SQL:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SELECT @startDate = '2015-11-18', @endDate = '2015-11-20' --yyyy-mm-dd
;WITH Calender AS (
    SELECT @startDate AS WorkDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT WorkDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE WorkDate + 1 <= @endDate
), -- generate date from to --
cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS 'total' ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY c.dt DESC) as row
        , c.* 
    FROM Calender d
    LEFT JOIN clockL c ON c.dt = d.WorkDate AND c.id = 17
) -- select user log and add missing dates --  
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
--WHERE row BETWEEN 0 AND 15
--option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Result:

```
total       row                  badgenumber id          name                                     title                deptname                       ld               dt           min          mout         ain          aout         nin          nout
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------ ---------------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
3           1                    1           17          James                                                         HQ                             2015-11-19 08:31 2015-11-19   08:31        NOC          NOC          NOC          NOC          NOC
3           2                    1           17          James                                                         HQ                             2015-11-18 20:37 2015-11-18   08:30        13:14        16:28        20:37        NOC          NOC
3           3                    NULL        NULL        NULL                                     NULL                 NULL                           NULL             NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL
                                    ^           ^           ^                                                           ^                                               ^                                               
                            should be 1     shoud be 17   James                                                         HQ                                          2015-11-20
```

thank you for looking :), i looked and tried but failed.

Comment: `SELECT ISNULL(badgenumber, 1), ISNULL(id, 17), ISNULL(name, 'James') 
FROM cte` I already know that you will be disappointed with this solution. Think about why I provided this solution...

Comment: The reason you have nulls there is because there is no row in the clockL table with date 2015-11-20, probably because that is in the future! Do you really want to return rows for days that haven't happened yet? If not, then I would suggest using an inner join or a right join in place of `FROM Calender d LEFT JOIN clockL`

Comment: Your are right but there are missing dates in clockL, what i'm trying to achieve is adding the missing dates and fill in some of the values  e.g **id**, **name**

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri, i tryed that but it needs to add the user id, doing this on cte won't help.